# dplyr bind_rows execution time exponential

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I've got a list (length = 5000) of tibbles that I want to merge. They've all got the same columns so I thought of merging using `dplyr::bind_rows`. On the face of it binding rows per each added tibble is very quick, however the execution time increases exponentially instead of linearly as more tibbles are being added.
Having done some googling, it's very much like the bug observed here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1396. Even though the bug is supposed to have been fixed in the bind_rows internals, I'm still seeing an exponential increase in elapsed time per tibble.

```
library(foreach)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123456)
tibbles <- foreach(i = 1:200) %do% {
              tibble(a = rnorm(10000), 
                     b = rep(letters[1:25], 400), 
                     c = rnorm(10000))
}
times <- foreach(i = 1:200) %do% {
            system.time(tibbles[1:i] %>% 
                            purrr::reduce(bind_rows))
}

times %>% 
     map_dbl(.f = ~.x[3]) %>% 
     plot(ylab = "time [s] per added tibble")
```

Any ideas why this is the case and how to solve it?

Thanks.

[image: elapsed_time]

Comment: growing data frame row by row is inefficient. `data.table` can help you better here.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can't you use `bind_rows` on the tibble directly instead of via `purrr:reduce`?  Things look linear to me with that change.

Comment: No, it was me who misunderstood - I didn't know you could use it on a list. Thanks for that. Got the job done in no time at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that every time you call `rbind`, R has to allocate a new set of columns and copy the data over. This would lead to a quadratic increase in time.

Try pre-allocating the columns instead:

```
system.time({
n <- vapply(tibbles, nrow, 0)
ntot <- sum(n)
cols <- list(a = numeric(ntot), b = character(ntot), c = numeric(ntot))

off <- 0
for (i in seq_along(tibbles)) {
    ix <- off + seq_len(n[[i]])
    for (j in seq_along(cols)) {
        cols[[j]][ix] <- tibbles[[i]][[j]]
    }
    off <- off + n[[i]]
}

result <- as_tibble(cols)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.073   0.012   0.085
```

Compare with the `purrr::reduce` approach:

```
system.time(tibbles[1:200] %>% purrr::reduce(bind_rows))
#>   user  system elapsed 
#>  4.888   2.013   6.928
```

Although, as aosmith notes, in your situation it's better to just use `bind_rows`:

```
system.time(result <- bind_rows(tibbles))
#>  user  system elapsed 
#> 0.039   0.005   0.044
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on abhiieor's comment, I think that `rbindlist` or `rbind` from data.table might be helpful. Assuming you are trying to bind the rows of a series of tibbles (or data.tables) this code is nearly instant.

```
time <- proc.time()

data_tables <- foreach(i = 1:200) %do% {
  data.table(a = rnorm(10000), 
         b = rep(letters[1:25], 400), 
         c = rnorm(10000))
}

all_tables <- rbindlist(data_tables)

end_time <- proc.time() -  time
```